Trace morphism in Deligne/Milne's "Tannakian categories"
I originally posted this on MSE, but only got a comment linking an article (Bontea and Nikshych's "Pointed braided tensor categories").  So I'll repost the question in full here:
Is there a connection between the trace morphism (1.7.3 in Deligne and Milne's Tannakian categories) and characters of finite groups?
I am also trying to understand why 1.7.4 on the same page (ibid.) holds. Any clarification on this would be much appreciated.
I tried finding something more in Etingof et al.'s book "Tensor Categories" about this.
Would for example $\operatorname{rank}(X) = \operatorname{tr}_X(\mathrm{id}_X)$ correspond to the dimension of a representation $(V, \rho)$ in $\operatorname{Rep}_G$ in some functorial sense (i.e. as $\operatorname{tr}(\rho(1_G))$)?
Perhaps I am wildly off.
One finds that 1.7.5 follows from 1.7.4 so that $\operatorname{rank}(X \otimes X') = \operatorname{rank}(X) \cdot \operatorname{rank}(X')$ is just an application of the first equation in 1.7.4.
Similarly, we have
$
\operatorname{rank}(\mathbb{1}) := \operatorname{tr}_{\mathbb{1}}(\mathrm{id}_{\mathbb{1}}) = \mathrm{id}_{\mathbb{1}}$ by the second equation in 1.7.4.
I suppose that $\operatorname{tr}_{\mathbf{1}}:\operatorname{End}(\mathbf{1}) \to \operatorname{End}(\mathbf{1})$ reduces to the identity in $\operatorname{End}(\mathbf{1})$. But is there an explicit way to make this clear?
To summarize: I am mainly interested in the following two questions, ordered by importance:

How does one prove that the two equations in 1.7.4 hold?

Is there a connection to characters $\chi:G \to \mathbb{C}$ of a representation of a finite group $G$ (for simplicity, assuming complex representation; I think perhaps one needs at least characteristic $0$, see footnote on the same page)?


Edit: Although, I did realize that originally, my reference to the relevant equalities in Deligne/Milne was off, so that may perhaps have confused some readers on MSE.
Edit 2: They do reference Saavedra Rivano's 1972 "Catégories Tannakiennes" page I, 5.1.4; I tried translating what I believed was the relevant part to english with GPT4, but failed to understand exactly what the text intended to convey.
